# Why do my divs flush to the left at different viewports?

Tags: html, css, background-image

Video:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SWMcMN7lS7TsAltLim9VXnvss4S3B__f/view

Deployed page:
https://swyner97.github.io/LA-Mountains/

please these out to see the full issue.

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources to be understood become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed. Create a [MCVE] and put it in **the question itself** instead. Stackoverflow does support [inline live demos](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Answer (score -1):

Because of the margins on the inline elements inside of it, `#nav2` can not be smaller than a certain width, which causes the div with the mountain logo inside of it to collapse to two lines.

You can prevent the logo div from collapsing by giving it a `min-width` or a `flex-basis`.

I would probably use flex in `#nav2` as well, rather than inline elements. This would give more control over the flow of the elements.

Comment: I am using flex in #nav2 though